# Set ssh to connect to specific users on specific servers

Tags: ssh

I would like to not have to type the user I ssh to a server as when I ssh to said server.

If there was a way I could set ssh to only connect to servers x and y with username z, that would be good. It still has to connect to all other servers with my username.

That seems like the only possibility right now, because I don't want to do any of the following:

- change my username
- make an alias for ssh ( `ssh = ssh -l z` )
- create a script that is specific for a single server.

I'm starting to think this isn't really possible in the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a ~/.ssh/config file or edit your existing one.

and an entry like this;

```
Host foo
    HostName foo.bar.com
    Port 22
    User username
```

Then you can just type ssh foo

Comment: A million thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Side question, where can I find out more about this config file? The man pages don't say much on it.

Comment: This is a good article http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/